# file read/write on RAM in android

Tags: ram, file-access

currently my app read and write a file from /mnt/sdcard path.ans my app contain lot of file read and write operation.I like to speed up file read and write operation.
   can anybody tell me, how to read and write a file in android RAM drive or app's internal storage?

Answer (score -1):

When using storage, if the user uninstalls the app, except External Storage, all other data such as files, internal storage data, settings will be deleted permanently. So, depending upon your need, you can choose any of the following.

To use Internal Storage file operations, http://developer.android.com/intl/es/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal

To use `SharedPreferences` which is faster as it does not require file operations,
http://developer.android.com/intl/es/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref

And for other storage options,refer http://developer.android.com/intl/es/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html